# How to share the same properties file for Java and jQuery i18n

Tags: java, properties, internationalization

I try to use properties file to manage the string text.

For now , the java's property file is located at `src/org/XXX/lang/bundle`, and the jQuery.i18's is located at `WebContent/i18n`.

Is there a way to share the same property file ?

Comment: Would it work to enhance your build progress, to copy over the file from the src directory into the i18n directory?

Comment: Do you wish to hold it in a relative path that is common to both? Otherwise you *may* copy over the file to `WebContent/i18n` but I don't quite like that

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to share the same properties file. One way suggested in a comment was to simply copy the file over; it could be easily done by the build script. Frankly it seem the easiest solution.
Other ways to share the file:

- A servlet or a web service that will return the required content on HTTP GET request (i.e. dynamically generate required language file) - requires some coding,
- You can use the same method you are using to translate the html templates (whatever technology you're using, JSP, Thymeleaf?) to either generate an array to be used by jQuery or create pre-translated HTML pieces (i.e. Handlebars templates).

The choice depends on the technology stack as well as requirements (i.e. response time); definitely it will be faster if you already have pre-translated HTML parts that you can reuse, generating HTML from strings always brings overhead.